# Scala JSR 223 importing types/classes

Tags: scala, jsr223

The following example fails because the definition for `Stuff` can't be found:

```
package com.example

import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

object Driver5 extends App {
  case class Stuff(s: String, d: Double)
  val e = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
  println(e.eval("""import Driver5.Stuff; Stuff("Hello", 3.14)"""))
}
```

I'm unable to find any import statement that allows me to use my own classes inside of the `eval` statement. Am I doing something wrong? How does one import classes to be used during `eval`?

EDIT: Clarified example code to elicit more direct answers.

Answer (score 0):

The Scripting engine does not know the context. It surely can't access all the local variables and imports in the script, since they are not available in the classfiles. (Well, variable names may be optionally available as a debug information, but it is virtually impossible to use them for this purpose.)

I am not sure if there is a special API for that. Imports are different across various languages, so bringing an API that should fit them all can be difficult.

You should be able to add the imports to the eval-ed String. I am not sure if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Imports in the eval string don't work -- they can't see the namespaces from my project at all, almost as if they are in a separate JVM.

Comment: So you problem does not lie in the imports, it lies in the visibility. How do you run the script? I've some suspicion about the classloaders. Maybe try calling `new ScriptEngineManager(getClass.getClassLoader)`. I am not sure if this helps. If it does not help, it would deny my suspicion about classloaders.

Comment: I've tried manipulating the classpath object used in script engine construction -- had no effect. The no argument version should use the current thread's loader.